# Duplicated keys in Tree Map when accesing concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, treemap, sortedmap

Can someone find the concurrency error in this code? The code is working perfectly fine for one thread but as soon I start 2 threads at the same times and I call the addScore method, it is adding duplicates to the tree Map.

The pojo with the comparedTO overrided is as follows:

```
public final class UserHighScore implements Comparable<UserHighScore>{

    private final int userId;
    private final int value;

    public UserHighScore(int userId, int value) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof UserHighScore)) {
            return false;
        }
        UserHighScore userHighScore = (UserHighScore) obj;
        return userHighScore.userId==userId;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(UserHighScore uh) {
        if(uh.getUserId()==this.getUserId()) return 0;
        if(uh.getValue()>this.getValue()) return 1;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This is the code that I'm using to simulate a User making requests:

```
class User implements Runnable
{

    private ScoreServiceImpl scoreService=ScoreServiceImpl.getInstance();

    CountDownLatch latch;
    public User(CountDownLatch latch)
    {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            scoreService.addScore(3,Integer.parseInt(Thread.currentThread().getName()),ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(50000));
        }
        System.out.println(scoreService.getHighScoreList(3));
    }
}
```

And the main method to create the threads is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    SpringApplication.run(RestclientApplication.class, args);

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    User user1=new User(latch);
    User user2=new User(latch);
    Thread t1=new Thread(user1);
    Thread t2=new Thread(user2);
    t1.setName("1");
    t2.setName("2");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    //latch.countDown();
}
```

Comment: How are you able to tell that duplicates are being put into the map?

Comment: Because when I debug I see the map having more than one key for the same userId, and when I print the list I can see that as well

Comment: For me there should not be more than a entry by userId (does not matter the score), however that is working fine for one thread but not for two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compareTo is screwy. You can get the same result single threaded with something like this

```
    ScoreServiceImpl.getInstance().addScore(0,1,4);
    ScoreServiceImpl.getInstance().addScore(0,1,12);
    ScoreServiceImpl.getInstance().addScore(0,0,10);
    ScoreServiceImpl.getInstance().addScore(0,0,3);
```

Tree sets work by divide and conquer, it checks the guy in the middle first. (which will will be 1, 4) and since the userIds don't match it doesn't compare them and compares the values instead. if it had compared the userids it would have gone left but instead it went right and only compared items with a userid of one

You can either *always* compare on both values or *always* compare on just userId but you can't switch back and forth.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(UserHighScore uh) {
    return Integer.compare(userId, uh.userId);
}
```

Comment: So according to your answer,  it is just not possible to use a custom object as a key in a treemap, to have at the same time unicity and ordering of the keys, am I right?

Comment: @fgonzalez sure you can, you just need a correct `compareTo` implementation.

Comment: But if I can only compare by one field or another, I don't see the correct implementation, either I do that return Integer.compare(userId, uh.userId);  or I do that return Integer.compare(value,uh.value); in my compareTo Implementation.    In the first case, keys will be unique but unsorted, and in the second case they will be sorted but duplicated, see my point?

Comment: If you compare by both fields then 0,1 and 0,2 aren't going to match and you'll see "duplicates" every time. the compareTo method only returns a single number so you can't do what you want to, which is to make it say "Well... it's really the same entry BUT i wan't it to be on the left"

I would only compare on userId and then after you gotten that user back in the util method *then* compare the values

Comment: Additionally, if you only want one entry for each user, why do have the score value as part of the key? Shouldn't the key just be the userId? You don't have to worry about sorting the userId *and* the value because you only ever want one value per user at a time

Comment: Well, initially I put the score as part of the key because TreeMap only sorts on the keys, not the values, and I don't care about sorting the userId's but the scores; and I thought that it was possible what I was trying to achieve, if I'm not going to get the scores sorted using my own object then using TreeMap is useless, in that case I'd go with a HashMap and then I will sort the map each time a ordered list is requested (which it was what initially I was trying to avoid, I would have prefered to return the list already sorted without any processing).

Comment: @fgonzalez: it’s impossible to say whether it is possible to achieve what you are trying, as it is entirely impossible to recognize what you are trying. Your `compareTo` method is broken in *multiple* ways. So, well, can you explain in simple words *what* you want to achieve? What is the desired result?

Comment: @Holger: Yes, let's say that in a game a user can gets an score, and I need to return a ordered list with the highest scores per user sorted by score: So I thought the most efficcient way it was to add a custom object userHighscore as a key in a tree map to get theses keys sorted automatically when I put these objects in the tree, but it seems I can not get unicity and sorting because in the compareTo I cannot use both fields (userId and value(score)) as mike mentioned above –

Comment: Yeah, you want the list *ordered* by score, but only one element for each user. You could do that with just a regular list, but you'll hurt the efficiency during each insertion because it will have to check **all** existing elements to see if that user already exists. On the other hand you could maintain the list sorted by user id (which would allow java to check for duplicates much faster) and then just run a single separate sort when you want to show the ordered high scores (i think that's what you're thinking about using the HashMap for, but you could use the TreeSet just the same)

Comment: @fgonzalez: the implied `TreeMap` manipulations, which would be to remove the previous user-score association, followed by adding the new one, permanently done on each score change and by multiple threads which block each other, is *very unlikely* to be more efficient than simply sorting a list right when the sorted list is required. You are doing the same work, just earlier and more often than required. Even filling a `TreeMap` exactly one time isn’t more efficient than sorting a list containing the same key elements one time.